# Single column Tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx

I would like to create a fixed width, single column `tabularx` with centered text which is entirely enclosed. For some reason the width of the cell does not take the table with.

How can I archieve this goal?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
    \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabularx}{5cm}{|c|}
                \hline
                First Argument\\ \hline
                Second long Argument\\ \hline
                Third Argument\\ \hline
            \end{tabularx}
        \end{center}
    \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: singlecolumntabular]

Comment: What is the point in using tabularx if yiou just have one singe column and not even using an `X`column? Instead of `c`, use `X`?

Comment: or `p{5cm}`. Either way, you have to center the content.

Comment: how to center the content when using X or p?

Comment: I am open for a solution to solve this in tabular also!

Comment: There is no point in a single column table, and no point in a tabularx with no X column. What is the intended behaviour here?

Comment: Johannes_B could solve my issue already. I knew that there is probably no need for tabularx , since I don't use dynamic columns, especially because I only use a single column, but I could get as close to my goal with `tabularx` then with `tabular`. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: erikTabularx]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{5cm}|}
            \hline
            First Argument\\ \hline
            Second long Argument\\ \hline
            Third Argument\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: that's it! I was not aware of the `\arraybackslash`!